# UITableViewCell not displaying text correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a list of data from which I search for some items and then I select one of them which expand the selected cell. Then when I clear out the search text in search bar, I wish to display the original list. I am able to display all the items in the original list, except for the cell that was selected during search doesn't get updated. Attaching snapshots and code for better understanding:

[image: Original List]

[image: Search for text and select item on row 3]

[image: Clear search and display original list.]

Notice that row #3 in first image has text "A.B. Road" whereas the same row in third image uses the same cell as in second image (it should get updated to "A.B. Road") I am using a custom cell and tried creating a new cell everytime instead of reusing the existing cell. This didn't help.

Code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [self.branchList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

    CGSize labelSize = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cellFont} context:nil].size;

    CGFloat cellHeight = labelSize.height + 20;
    return [self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath] ? cellHeight * 5 : cellHeight;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *stateListCellId = @"stateList";

    BranchDetailsTableViewCell *stateListCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:stateListCellId];

    if (!stateListCell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BranchDetailsTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:stateListCellId];
        stateListCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:stateListCellId];
    }

    return stateListCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.expandedCells removeObject:indexPath];

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
    else {
        [self.activityIndicator showActivityIndicatorForView:self.navigationController.view];
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
        [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath];
        [self getDataFromService];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(BranchDetailsTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [self displayDataOnTheCell];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] != [self.branchListCopy count]) {
        [self.expandedCells removeAllObjects];
// Copy the original list to display.
        self.branchList = self.branchListCopy;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

It looks like it's just the cell that is not getting rendered again because when I debug, I do see "A.B. Road" in the array, it's the cell that is not displaying it. I tried calling "[cell setNeedsDisplay]" and also creating new cell always instead of reusing, but nothing helped. What else could help?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but the problem may be where you call [self displayDataOnTheCell]. Try to do that inside cellForRowAtIndexPath as that gets called for sure when you call [self.tableView reloadData], even if the cell is already displayed. Also, I would recommend to do place this [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BranchDetailsTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:stateListCellId] call inside view controller... that way you can remove if (!stateListCell) { /*...*/ } check inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @ppalancica - Tried that, didn't help. I think something is caching the cell. I even tried overriding prepareForReuse method on the cell and setting the text to nil there, that didn't work either.

Comment: I may write a blog post for the solution. Maybe next week, will see. It's not that hard, you probably missed some small detail somewhere...

Comment: Yes could be. This only happens when I click on a cell from after the search results after searching. If I just search and do not click on any cell and clear out the search, then I see my original list back. Let me know if you need more code to save up some time. Thanks @ppalancica!

Comment: Alright, @ppalancica I was able to get it working. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath if I execute [tableview reloadData] instead of beginUpdates, reloadRowsAtIndexPath, endUpdates then it works fine. I didn't understood why "tableview reloadData" works or why "tableview reloadRows..." is caching the cell, but I will read more about how both of those methods works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it work by replacing the below code with `[tableview reloadData]` in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method keeping rest of the code as is.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

***Final working solution:***

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [self.branchList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

    CGSize labelSize = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cellFont} context:nil].size;

    CGFloat cellHeight = labelSize.height + 20;
    return [self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath] ? cellHeight * 5 : cellHeight;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *stateListCellId = @"stateList";

    BranchDetailsTableViewCell *stateListCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:stateListCellId];

    if (!stateListCell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BranchDetailsTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:stateListCellId];
        stateListCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:stateListCellId];
    }

    return stateListCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self.expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.expandedCells removeObject:indexPath];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else {
        [self.activityIndicator showActivityIndicatorForView:self.navigationController.view];
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
        [self.expandedCells addObject:indexPath];
        [self getDataFromService];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the same cell identifier for each cell. Try to use different cell identifiers:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//NSString *stateListCellId = @"stateList";

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
    BranchDetailsTableViewCell *stateListCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    if (!stateListCell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BranchDetailsTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:stateListCellId];
        stateListCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:stateListCellId];
    }

    return stateListCell;
}
```

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of having the same identifier was to reuse the cell instead of creating new everytime. But I tried this too and didn't help. I feel like something is caching the cell. I even tried overriding prepareForReuse method on the cell and setting the text to nil there, that didn't work either.

Comment: I also was confused about not reusing cells. But I had a similar problem to what you have and creating individual identifiers fixed. My table contains a lot of content, text, images and videos, and I did not run into any issue  with memory or performance. So I guess not reusing cell identifiers is fine.